# apache not start

Tags: apache, centos

I'm tryning to install apache and php on centos, I did install this:

```
yum install httpd
yum install php
/etc/init.d/httpd start
```

and all ok, I check with

```
http://localhost/
```

but I don't know why but when I do now

```
/etc/init.d/httpd start
```

show

```
Starting httpd: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using localhost.localdomain for ServerName
```

Sorry but I'm very noob with servers.

Thanks you very much.

Comment: This is better suited over at http://serverfault.com/

Comment: I suggest to check log files at `/var/log/httpd` directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On CentOS, the config file for httpd should be /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf by default.  Edit that file and find the "ServerName" entry.  Uncomment that line by deleting the # at the beginning of the line and set the name to what you want.  Save the file and restart the server with:

```
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

Keep in mind that the message you are worried about is only a warning, not an error.